# How to preserve changes in templates and other files

Tags: templates, child-theme, updates, parent-theme

I've downloaded a theme and then changed some css styles, and also php templates etc. Then I've realized, that when I will have to update the theme I'll probably lose all my changes. Is this kind of problem possible to solve by using child theme? Or do I need something else?

Also, the other thing is, I don't exactly remember which files I've changed :/

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is the task of "child themes". To find changed files, you can download the theme again (the version you changed) and compare two directory (original and modified theme) with one of the [file comparison tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools).